# ruby on rails form_for self referential model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action, form-for

Here's a line from my form, used to create a relationship between two users

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
<%= f.submit "follow" %>
```

Relationship controller create method:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
  current_user.follow!(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.js
  end
end
```

I'm trying to figure out how to move the current_user.relationships.build logic out of the form and into the controller, is it possible?

Comment: Could you post your form code?

Comment: indeed, quite hard to answer without the form you're talking about

Comment: I'm sorry I added it, but not sure why it didn't show up. Anyways here it is
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
<%= f.submit "follow" %>
I edited the question to include the form code as well. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to move the logic out of the form.
Basically the object being passed to the form_for helper needs to be initialized. I put the initialization logic into user helper and passed the method to the form_for helper. so this is what you get

user helper method

```
def initializing_relationships
 current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id)
end
```

in the form you call initializing_relationships

```
<%= form_for(initializing_relationships) do |f| %>
```

This really cleans up the form.